# Not able to run drush in drupal 8 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, drupal-8, drush, lampp

I am try to run drush in drupal 8 . I am using LAMPP in my ubuntu system . Current drush version is 8.1.15 . When I run `drush cr` in my root dir it showing me error 
[image]

Please help out to solve this error .
Thankyou

Comment: I suppose PDO_mysql module was missing.

Comment: @Chandraveer How do I install in my ubuntu system. I already install LAMPP .

Comment: On a Linux server you can compile php with the following option --with-pdo-mysql In your php.ini, add the following lines
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so